# How to find this checkbox "Allow this code to be different from the original"?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, breakpoints, pdb-files

I tried following this path the message suggests but there but wasn't able to find "Location" after moving to "Settings". Where is this checkbox?

[image]

Comment: If you hover over the breakpoint, do you see the settings cog? And please don't add unrelated tags to your question: there is nothing here related to NuGet.

Answer (score 3):

While it is possible to do that, you should think about whether you want this. Having the wrong PDBs or having the wrong source code may lead you into wrong conclusions about what you're debugging.

You should only activate this if you know about the consequences, and the consequences are:

- you cannot really trust what you see
- you may make wrong conclusions
- you may change source code which is not affected by your bug
- if you change code, you may introduce new bugs instead of fixing the bug

With that warning spoken:

In Visual Studio 2019:

1. Right click the breakpoint

[image: Right click breakpoint]

2. Click on `Conditions...` or `Actions...` (It seems that `Settings...` is no longer available)

[image: Breakpoint settings]

3. Click on the link and change the checkbox

[image: Allow source to be different]